# MakeTable with "with"

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I try to combine "select * into"  with "with"

```
drop table #a
create table #a(a1 int);

insert into #a (a1) values (1),(2);


select * into #b(--I try this syntax and have error mentioned below
    with a as
    (
        select * from #a
    )
    select * from a
)
```

> Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.

How I can resolve this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the common table expression before the actual `insert`:

```
drop table #a;
create table #a(a1 int);

insert into #a (a1) values (1),(2);

with a as (
  select * 
  from #a
)
select * 
  into #b
from a;
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for common table expressions can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms175972%28v=sql.120%29.aspx):

```
drop table #a 
create table #a(a1 int)

insert into #a (a1) values (1),(2)


;with a as (
    select * from #a
) 
select * into #b from a;
```